# How do you know what variable to replace for a time derivative?

Tags: derivatives

I am a avid reader of Physics articles, and enjoy the mathematics greatly. I have taught myself most of the needed mathematics however one part of it always messes me up. When you take a time derivative, I have read that you have to replace a variable that is dependent to time, with time.

[Wiki Article on Time Derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_derivative)

If this is true, then it must apply to other variables as well. Which would make it very difficult to take the time derivative of a equation with 5 different variables dependent to time, so how would you know which variable to replace?

The Article Says:

consider a particle moving in a circular path. Its position is given by the displacement vector $$r=x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}$$, related to the angle, $$θ$$, and radial distance, r, as defined in the figure:

$$x = r  \cos\theta$$
$$y = r \sin\theta$$

For purposes of this example, time dependence is introduced by setting θ = t. The displacement (position) at any time t is then

$$f{r}(t) = r\cos(t)\hat{i}+r\sin(t)\hat{j}$$
This form shows the motion described by $$r(t)$$ is in a circle of radius r because the magnitude of r(t) is given by

$$|f{r}(t)| = \sqrt{f{r}(t) \cdot f{r}(t)}=\sqrt {x(t)^2 + y(t)^2 } = r\, \sqrt{\cos^2(t) + \sin^2(t)} = r$$

using the trigonometric identity $$\sin^2(t) + \cos^2(t) = 1 $$

If I need to take a time derivative of a function that has multiple variables dependent to time, but the function itself has not time variable, how would I Differentiate it with to respect to time?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be _anything_ in the Wikipedia article you link to that speaks about "you have to replace a variable that is dependant to time, with time". The word "replace" doesn't even occur in the article. Where did you find that strange-sounding claim?

Comment: "For purposes of this example, time dependence is introduced by setting θ = t. The displacement (position) at any time t is then"

Answer (score 1):

That does NOT say anything about "replace a variable that is dependent on time, with time".   It says that they are "introducing" time by replacing a variable by time.  If you have function of a number of variables that are themselves functions of time, the derivative of that function, with respect to time, is found using the  chain rule.
If f is a function of x, y, and z, with x, y, and z functions of t then 
$\frac{df}{dt}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}$.

Answer (score 0):

If the location $(x,y)$ is defined by a single parameter $\theta$ then

$$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} (x,y) = (\dot{x},\dot{y})= \left( \dot{\theta} \frac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d} \theta} , \dot{\theta} \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d} \theta} \right) $$

where $\dot{\theta}$ is the time derivative of the parameter. For example with $(x,y) = (r \cos \theta,r \sin \theta)$ you have

$$(\dot{x},\dot{y}) = \left(\dot{\theta} \frac{{\rm d}(r \cos \theta)}{{\rm d}\theta},\dot{\theta} \frac{{\rm d}(r \sin \theta)}{{\rm d}\theta}\right) = \left(-r \dot{\theta} \sin\theta, r \dot{\theta} \cos\theta \right) $$

The above is often denoted with the shorthand that when a variable $x$ depends on a parameter $q$ then $\boxed{\dot{{\bf x}} = {\bf x}'\dot{q}}$ where ${\bf x}'$ denoted derivative in terms of the parameter $q$ and $\dot{q}$ the derivative of the parameter in terms of time.

Here is where it gets exciting. The velocities above are a function of both $\theta$ *and* $\dot{\theta}$ so to calculate the accelerations the following chain rule is used:

$$(\dot{x},\dot{y}) = (v,u)$$
$$(\ddot{x},\ddot{y}) = \left( \dot{\theta} \frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}\theta} + \ddot{\theta} \frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}\dot{\theta}}, \dot{\theta} \frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}\theta} + \ddot{\theta} \frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}\dot{\theta}}\right) $$

For example when that $(v,u) = (-r \dot{\theta} \sin\theta, r \dot{\theta} \cos\theta)$ the acceleration is

$$\begin{aligned} \frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}\theta} & = -r \dot{\theta}\cos\theta & \frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}\theta} & = -r \dot{\theta}\sin\theta  \\ \frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}\dot{\theta}} & = -r \sin \theta & \frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}\dot{\theta}} & = r \cos \theta \end{aligned} $$

$$(\ddot{x},\ddot{y}) = \left( -r \dot{\theta}^2 \cos\theta - r \ddot{\theta} \sin\theta, -r \dot{\theta}^2 \sin\theta + r \ddot{\theta} \cos\theta \right)$$

or with the shorthand $\boxed{ \ddot{{\bf x}} = {\bf x}' \ddot{q} +{\bf  x}'' \dot{q}^2}$